# How do i separate two error message in laravel using one error blade file?

Tags: laravel

Say,i have two form in one page.I have included one error blade file bellow both of the form. Now when i make wrong in one form & submit it the error message is showing bellow the both form.Its normal.But my question is, how do i separate this two error message,how can i differentiate by giving them two different name?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
    'form1.name' => 'name is required in Form 1',
    'form1.email' => 'email is required in Form 1',
    'form2.city' => 'city is required in form 2'
]);
```

in your view

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->get('form1.*') as $error) {
       {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

So you can group errors by form using array notation `form.name` and get all with `$errors->get('form.*)`.

Read more about errors here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation), you can change the [`errorBag`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L55-L60) property to get a unique array of errors for your view file.

In your `Request` file:

```
class MyFormRequest {
    protected $errorBag = 'foobar';

    public function rules() { // ... }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function store(MyFormRequest $request) {
    // Store entry.
}
```

Then in your view file:

```
@if ($errors->foobar->isNotEmpty())
// Work with the errors
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the named error bags.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'field1' => 'required',
    'field2' => 'required|digits:1',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()
                ->withErrors($validator, 'form1error')
                ->withInput();
}
```

To print the error in blade file use-

```
@if(count($errors->form1error)>0)
  <ul>
  @foreach($errors->form1error->all() as $error)
    <li>{{$error}}</li>
  @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```